# how to shift a line on a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with two lines on it.

My code generates the line. The problem is the sometimes the line are identical and then the map shows them as one line.

In that case I want to shift one of the lines a bit so the map will show 2 lines.

I thought to use this:

```
type = "LineString";
        double offset = isBl? 0.0001 : 0.0;
        coordinates = alt.coords.stream()
                .map(p -> new double[]{p.x, p.y + offset})
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

But the result still shows one line

[image]

examples for my shift:

1st line: 1st point is
-73.70651169690616
40.707901384869466

2nd line: 1st point is 
-73.70651169690616
40.707901384869466

how can I shift one line to be aside the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a higher degree and it worked:

```
    double offset = isBl? 0.005 : 0.0;
```